# How do i add texture(.png file) in urdf

Tags: ros, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to add png file in my urdf like below but its now working:

```
    <visual>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.078335"/>
  <geometry>
    <mesh filename="package://myrobot1_description/meshes/velodyne_base.dae"/>
  </geometry>
  <material>
    <script>
      <uri>package://myrobot1_description/materials/scripts</uri>
      <uri>package://myrobot1_description/materials/textures</uri>
      <name>Table/Marble_Lightmap</name>
    </script>
  </material>
</visual>
```

So how do i fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251455/how-do-i-add-texture(.png-file)-in-urdf/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your geometry is not a mesh, i.e. you have a basic geometry in your visual tag (box, sphere, cylinder), this should work:

Create a material file `example.material` (your_package/media/materials/scripts/example.material)

```
material YourMaterialName{
    technique
    {
        pass
        {
            texture_unit
            {
                texture your_material_image.jpg
                scale 1 1
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

This file can have multiple materials, not just this one. Then, outside the `<link>` tag of your URDF:

```
<gazebo reference="your_link">
    <material>YourMaterialName</material>
</gazebo>
```

However, if your geometry is a mesh, in addition you will need to prepare your mesh to receive the image. Open your mesh using Blender, then first imagine how would you cut your solid with a scissor in order to put all surfaces in a plane. Then, select those edges, press Ctrl+E and select Mark Seam. The edges will become red. Split the window into 2 and in the new window choose UV/Image Editor as the Editor Type (bottom left corner). Then, press A to select everything, press U and choose Unwrap. At the UV/Image Editor will appear a geometry showing all your object faces in a plane. Now you can export to COLLADA (.dae) and put in your visual geometry mesh.

If you could not follow up the Blender steps, take a look at this tutorial: https://youtu.be/f2-FfB9kRmE

---

Originally posted by [hbaqueiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/37094/hbaqueiro/) with karma: 121 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have never used the variable`package:`, because I don't know where is it pointing. I use `file:` and `model:` successfully.  You can set the path for the `file:` variable  in GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH variable.

```
export $GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/path/to/you/resource/folder
```

Make sure that your "resource folder" is of structure

```
media
-materials
--textures
--scripts
```

Then you can use  tags to refer to your material name defined in the script files. You only need to add  to define which script to use, if you have multiple scripts that define the same named material.

```
<material>
          <script>
            <name>Gazebo/Texturename</name>
          </script>
</material>
```

or

```
<material>
          <script>
            <uri>materials://scripts/other_script.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Texturename</name>
          </script>
</material>
```

or

```
<material>
          <script>
            <uri>media://materials/scripts/other_script.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Texturename</name>
          </script>
</material>
```

or

```
<material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/other_script.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Texturename</name>
          </script>
</material>
```

since the resource folder is searched for folders media -> materials -> scripts or something like that. Try it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) with karma: 308 on 2018-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2